# formula to count the number edges of a square, cube and tesseract

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

Given $4$ equidistant points, and the question *"how many line segments connect them?"*, you could rephrase the question to *"how many pairs are there in a tuple of 4?"* ("pairs" because a line segment is defined by a pair of points).

The answer would be $\frac{4!}{2!}(4-2)!=6$. But if you ask a child to connect the 4  points, they will draw a square. The two lines crossing the interior of the square are not considered. So the combinatoric formula given above does not actually compute the number of edges in a square.

With a cube we have one base, $8$ vertices, and $12$ edges. With a tesseract, there are $16$ vertices and $32$ edges. Is there a formula to compute the number edges of these shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the dimension of the object is $n$ then every vertex has $n$ neighbours. Since there are $2^n$ vertices, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}n2^n=n2^{n-1}$$.
The one half is there not to count edges twice.

Comment: thank you for the formula. I marked it as an answer because it works. I would like to understand but I am confused. by your first statement. How do you define 'neighbors'? Why are the points 'diagonally away' from a vertex not considered neighbors? Although I can visualize how this formula works in the second and third dimensions, my puny brain cannot do it in 4 dimensions. I am trying to prove it to my self and the best way would be if i could see a derivation. Unfortunately, search engines are not giving me what I want (maybe I am using the wrong words)

Comment: A generalized square can be considered to have vertices of the form (a_1,...,a_n) where a_i is 0 or 1. (See this is true for dimension 2) Then neighbors are vertices with exactly one differing coordinate. (Again check for dimension 2). Now the combinatorics should be clearer.

Comment: so a 3 dimensional cube would be represented by a matrix like [(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),etc] There would be 8 elements to that matrix because there are 8 vertices in a cube. But a cube has 3 neighbors. So that notation does not work for all dimensions in defining neighbors. I know I am ignorant and do not want to trouble you. Do you have a reference I can read?

Comment: No n is the dimension Of the object.